# How to add locales to iOS flutter app without using Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, localization, internationalization

The [Flutter i18n guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization#localizing-for-ios-updating-the-ios-app-bundle) notes that iOS apps should define supported locales in an `Info.plist` file. The guide then proceeds to give instructions that, as far as I understand, apply to the Xcode GUI. However, I do not have Xcode - or even a mac - and am planning on using GitHub actions to produce iOS builds. How can I perform the documented actions manually?

> Typically, iOS applications define key application metadata, including supported locales, in an Info.plist file that is built into the application bundle. To configure the locales supported by your app, use the following instructions:
>
> 1. Open your project’s ios/Runner.xcworkspace Xcode file.
> 2. In the Project Navigator, open the Info.plist file under the Runner project’s Runner folder.
> 3. Select the Information Property List item. Then select Add Item from the Editor menu, and select Localizations from the pop-up menu.
> 4. Select and expand the newly-created Localizations item. For each locale your application supports, add a new item and select the locale you wish to add from the pop-up menu in the Value field. This list should be consistent with the languages listed in the supportedLocales parameter.
> 5. Once all supported locales have been added, save the file.

Comment: Localization on iOS in flutter is dependent on Mac's there is no running away from it

Comment: All the GUI does is modify files on disk - it's got to be possible to do the same with a text editor.

Comment: You can edit info.plist with a text editor. It is just an XML file.  A comment though, I think you will struggle to develop for iOS, even in Flutter, without a Mac.

Comment: @FelixZY I am not saying you cannot do it, but you will have to do a lot of RnD to find the correct commands to do this